# Android web browser, check if url is a file

Tags: android, url, android-intent

I'm making a browser android application.

How do you determine if the url is a file? Like when you click a download button. Currently webView just loads and does nothing.

Do I need to check if the url ends with an extension and open it through intents? or is there another way?

Answer (score 4):

You can do as following:

1) Check if the url is file:

```
if(URLUtil.isFileUrl(file)){
    getExtention(url);
}
```

2) Get the extension:

```
public String getExtention(String url) {
    String filenameArray[] = url.split("\\.");
    String extension = filenameArray[filenameArray.length-1];
    return extension;
}
```

Trigger intent according to the extension:

```
if(getExtention(url).equals("jpg")){
    openGallery(url);
}
else if(getExtention(url).equals("pdf")){
    openPDF(url);
}
```

3.a) OpenGallery() as ex:

```
public void openGallery(String url){
    Uri uri =  Uri.parse(url);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(photoUri, "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

3.b) Open Pdf

```
public void openPdf(String url){
   Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
   startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

Hope this helps.